# Error while boot loading Atmega 2560 using Arduino Mega 2560

Tags: arduino-mega, bootloader, atmega2560

I have developed custom board using Atmega 2560. I am doing boot loading process using the process of migrate from an Arduino board to a standalone microcontroller.

[image: Custom Atmega 2560 Board]

I have followed this steps...

1) Upload the ArduinoISP sketch onto your Arduino board.

2) Wire up the Arduino board and microcontroller as connections mentioned on Arduino Site.

3) Select "Arduino/Genuino Mega/ Mega 2560" from the Tools > Board menu.

4) Select "Arduino as ISP" from Tools > Programmer

5) Run Tools > Burn Bootloader

While doing this process I am getting this Error...

> avrdude: Yikes!  Invalid device signature.
>            Double check connections and try again, or use -F to override
>            this check.
>   Error while burning bootloader.

I have done connection like this...

```
MISO  -  D50
MOSI  -  D51
SCK   -  D52
Reset -  D53/Reset
+5V   -  Vcc
GND   -  GND
```

What wrong I am doing? Or any step I have missed?

Comment: Is that a clone of mega just without the FTDI IC ?

Comment: @SagnikPradhan Yes it is a clone without FTDI IC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Same connections worked for me. Just one connection have to change.

```
Reset - D10
```

Answer (score 2):

You wired the whole thing backwards. The proper wiring is

```
Your board - Arduino
     MISO  -  D50
     MOSI  -  D51
     SCK   -  D52
     Reset -  D53
     Vcc   -  5V
     GND   -  GND
```

This is kind of obvious from the picture: you would normally use the ISP
connector of the *target* board.